# Align a pie chart and a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, pie

I want to put a table next to a pie chart.
I´m trying to put them in a table or in a matrix but the pie chart is a little higher than the table.

How can I put it well?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    Kromosoma & Hamartarra & $ f(x)$ & $f(x)/\sum_x f(x)$ \\ \hline
    01100 & 12 & 144 & 0,1181\\
    11001 & 25 & 625 & 0,5127\\
    00101 & 5 & 25 & 0,0205\\
    10011 & 19 & 361 & 0,2962 \\
    01000 & 8 & 64 & 0,0525\\\hline
    Batura && 1219\\
    \end{tabular} 
& 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[,radius=1.5,hide number,rotate = 90,text= inside]{10, 20, 30, 30, 10}
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `baseline` option for your tikzpicture (the outer tabular isn't really necessary, you could just place the elements besides each other):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    Kromosoma & Hamartarra & $ f(x)$ & $f(x)/\sum_x f(x)$ \\ \hline
    01100 & 12 & 144 & 0,1181\\
    11001 & 25 & 625 & 0,5127\\
    00101 & 5 & 25 & 0,0205\\
    10011 & 19 & 361 & 0,2962 \\
    01000 & 8 & 64 & 0,0525\\\hline
    Batura && 1219\\
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \pie[,radius=1.5,hide number,rotate = 90,text= inside]{10, 20, 30, 30, 10}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

as Sam Carter just posted you could adjust the baseline, but often it's good to position such things "by eye" adjust the offsets here to taste:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c c c c}
    Kromosoma & Hamartarra & $ f(x)$ & $f(x)/\sum_x f(x)$ \\ \hline
    01100 & 12 & 144 & 0,1181\\
    11001 & 25 & 625 & 0,5127\\
    00101 & 5 & 25 & 0,0205\\
    10011 & 19 & 361 & 0,2962 \\
    01000 & 8 & 64 & 0,0525\\\hline
    Batura && 1219\\
    \end{tabular} 
& 
    \hspace{-10pt}%
    \raisebox{-40pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[,radius=1.5,hide number,rotate = 90,text= inside]{10, 20, 30, 30, 10}
    \end{tikzpicture}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```